# How to add user on a mysql server via php code?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've created simple code that has to add user on mysql through PHP, but it doesn't. Here is the code.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
Login: <input type='text' name='login' /> <br/>
Pass: <input type='pass' name='pass' /> <br/>
<input type='submit'>
</form>

<?php
$c=mysql_connect('localhost','test','test');

$login=$_POST['login'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$t="CREATE USER '".$login."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '".$pass."';";

if($login!=NULL){
  if($q=mysql_query($t,$c))
  {
    echo "CREATED!";
  }else{
    die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
  }
}
?>
```

> Error: Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Take out the word `PASSWORD`. By using that keyword, it suggests you're providing the hash. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 0):

Take out the word `PASSWORD`. By using that keyword, it suggests you're providing the hash. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html

You want this:

```
$t="CREATE USER '".$login."'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '".$pass."';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <?php
 $host="localhost";
 $user="root";
 $password="";
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <title>MyExample</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create user in MySQL by FORM</h1>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        mysqli_query($con,"CREATE USER '".$username."'@'".$host."' IDENTIFIED BY '".$password."'");
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: By the way , mysql_connect is deprecated